# declaration of \newcommand results in missing \begin{document}

Tags: macros

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

\author{}
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-1mm}{%
    \textcolor{color1}{%
      \rule{2ex}{2ex}\hspace{5mm}}%
      \section{#1}%
  }%
}%
\begin{document}
\colorsection{test}
\end{document}
```

---

`xelatex f.tex` results in:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
[...]

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21 \colorsection{test}

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I have checked the bracket pairs, which is fine.

**My Question**

Where is my error? I don't see it.

Comment: You forgot the backslash of `colorsection` it its definition.  (however, your MWE left out a bunch of other stuff too, like `\usepackage{xcolor}` and a definition of `color1` which I am not even sure is valid with a nonalphabetic character)

Comment: you are missing _lots_ of `%` from ends of lines so you have a lot of spurious white space in the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\mbox{\section{abc}}
\end{document}
```

`\raisebox` makes a horizontal (LR) box like `\mbox` so vertical display constructs like `\section` are not allowed.

---

unrelated to the error but if you took `\section` out of the box:

```
 \raisebox{-1mm}{
    \textcolor{color1}{
      \rule{2ex}{2ex}\hspace{5mm}}}
```

That would have two word spaces to the left of the rule, one at the start of the raised box and one at the start of the coloured area. Almost certainly this should be coded as

```
 \raisebox{-1mm}{%
    \textcolor{color1}{%
      \rule{2ex}{2ex}\hspace{5mm}}
```

Although the `\hspace` there isn't having any visible effect if the following section heading is anyway coming below this.

Comment: As a follow up question: What can i use as an alternative? I want basically a moderncv \section in the \article class. Or should i ask this separately?

Comment: @toogley just take the section out of the `\raisebox`  what would you want `\raisebox` to do to  display heading?

Comment: @DavidCharlisle nope, the colored box is placed above the `\section` - whereas I want it to the left of `\section`. I think, its more useful, if i just open another question :D

Comment: @DavidCharlisle I just found http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306604/76157 which solves my follow up question pretty much.