# line break in "moderncv like \section" in the article class suggests missing \item

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

With the default definition of `\section` in the `article` class, I can make a multiline section header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\section{test \\ test}
\end{document}
```

[image: default section article]

The [following code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306610/76157), allows me to create a "moderncv like section" inside the article class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\author{}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

\makeatletter
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth} \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}%
\newlength{\baseletterheight} \settoheight{\baseletterheight}{o}%
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth} \setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}%
% fonts
\newcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}%
% styles
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont{#1}}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
   \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
                   {\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{%
                       \textcolor{color1}{%
                         \rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}\hspace*{%
                       \separatorcolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}}}}%
\par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{test test}
\end{document}
```

[image: moderncv like section in the article class]

However, if I change the `\section{test test}` to `\section{test \\ test}` to produce a line break like in the default definition of `\section`, I receive an error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \section{test \\ test}
```

As I understood `\item`, its just being used in lists like `itemize` or `enumerate`. Therefore this error message doesn't make sense to me in this context.

- How can I make this work?
- And what causes this odd error message?

Comment: same issue as your previous question, the text is in `\raisebox` which is like `\mbox` so can't have `\\ ` (and still missing `%` in  ends of line in the code, as before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, by setting the content of the section inside a `\parbox` which allows for using `\\`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

\makeatletter
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth} \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\baseletterheight} \settoheight{\baseletterheight}{o}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth} \setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}

% fonts
\newcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape\raggedright}

% styles
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-15pt}{\sectionfont #1}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
   \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
   \IfValueTF{#2}
     {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}}%
     {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}}%
   {\noindent\strut\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{%
      \textcolor{color1}{%
        \rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}\hspace*{%
          \separatorcolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#3}}}}}%
\par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[test test]{test \\ test}

\end{document}
```

I've added the option of specifying an optional argument like the typical `\section` for your ToC-related entries.

Comment: Could you please explain what `\hintscolumnwidth` and `\dimexpr` does in your code?

Comment: @toogley: You place the `\section` text a specific distance away from the left margin. This distance is given by `\hintscolumnwidth` + `\separatorcolumnwidth` + `15pt` which I remove from `\linewidth` to set a box that is the width of the line minus all the other elements that is set to the left of the text.